# How can I run test data against my keras trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The code to train my model is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv(
    "data/train.csv", header=0, usecols=['Type', 'Age', 'Breed1', 'Breed2', 'Gender', 'Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3', 'MaturitySize', 'FurLength',    'Vaccinated',   'Dewormed', 'Sterilized',   'Health',   'Quantity', 'Fee', 'VideoAmt', 'PhotoAmt'])
Y = pd.read_csv(
    "data/train.csv", header=0, usecols=['AdoptionSpeed'])

X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=["Type", "Breed1",
                               "Breed2", 'Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3', 'Gender', 'MaturitySize', 'FurLength'])
print(X)

Y = Y['AdoptionSpeed'].apply(lambda v: v / 4)

input_units = X.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_units, input_dim=input_units, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(input_units, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=250, batch_size=1000)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
```

I have a file called `test.csv`. How can I test that set against the model to see how effective my model is?

It seems to have a 97% accuracy with the training data, but I'm concerned it may be overfitting.

Comment: You can just read that file as you are reading the training files and then use `model.evaluate`.

Comment: @pooyan d'oh. Simple enough. If you post the answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to pick the best model to evaluate it on the test set you should firstly split the training set into training and validation set. Then you iteratively train and validate the model. The Keras `fit` method does that automatically for you.

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=250, batch_size=1000, validation_split=0.2)
```

As you can see, this will allocate 20% of the training set to be used as validation of the model.

Then, you should use the `test.csv` file you have only to measure how good the model you picked is. However, never do model selection with the test set. The test set is used so you can make an unbiased estimate of how good your model will perform in the real world.

Then I would load the `test.csv` file and use:

```
model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=Y_test)
```

Otherwise, if you just want to perform inference on the test set you can do:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

This method will return the predictions for your test set.

Comment: The problem is my `test.csv` doesn't have `AdoptionSpeed`. So how can I run the model on it to get the output values?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it same as your training approach as follow:

```
f = "test.csv"
X = pd.read_csv(
    f, header=0, usecols=['Type', 'Age', 'Breed1', 'Breed2', 'Gender', 'Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3', 'MaturitySize', 'FurLength',    'Vaccinated',   'Dewormed', 'Sterilized',   'Health',   'Quantity', 'Fee', 'VideoAmt', 'PhotoAmt'])
Y = pd.read_csv(
    f, header=0, usecols=['AdoptionSpeed'])

X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=["Type", "Breed1",
                               "Breed2", 'Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3', 'Gender', 'MaturitySize', 'FurLength'])
print(X)

Y = Y['AdoptionSpeed'].apply(lambda v: v / 4)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
```